# Compare a string in an array with a string after the array in the filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

`competences['asset']['id']`  return me string in array `['123']`;
`select[0]` return me string `'123'`

How  compare the string in the array with the string after the array so that it is on one line

```
.filter (obj => obj [" competences "]. map (competences => competences ['asset'] 
      ['id']) !== [select[0]]) // ['234']! = = '234
```

I'm trying to get inside the array:

```
obj["competences"].map (competences => competences['asset']['id'][0])
```

but this returns the first character of the string for me.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lwyqns

```
const people = [
  {
    'firstname': "Paul",
    'id': "12345", 
    'competences': [
      {'asset': {
          'name': "Paul",
          'id': '234'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

const select = [
  "123",
  "456",
  "789",
  "234"
]

const sort = people
  .filter(obj => obj["competences"].map(competences => competences['asset']['id']) !== select[0]) //['234'] !== '234'
  .map(
    (obj, i) => {
      return obj;
    }
  )

console.log(sort)
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra pull out string from array. compare string with string

Comment: you want to return whole people object as it is based on any asset Id match or you want to filter competences array too based on select Id.
Please post expected output with more data set, that will be helpful.

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra I updated my question. I forgot add  `!==`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @CharlieH If asset id object in people array (asset id = '234')  is  in array `select` return empty array

Comment: If not in the select array, what should be returned?

Comment: @CharlieH return empty array

Comment: So, weather the id is found in select or not you need to return empty array?

Comment: @CharlieH If is in select I return empty array; If isn't in select I return array with it object

Answer (score 0):

Here's code for which return people object whose competences.$.asset.id not include in select id array.

```
const people = [
  {
    firstname: 'Paul',
    id: '12345',
    competences: [
      {
        asset: {
          name: 'Paul',
          id: '234'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    firstname: 'SPaul',
    id: '123456',
    competences: [
      {
        asset: {
          name: 'SPaul',
          id: '100'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

const select = ['123', '456', '789', '234'];
// if you want to return people data if all competences.asset.id not in select
const sort = people.filter((item) => item.competences.filter((x) => select.indexOf(x.asset.id) === -1).length === item.competences.length);
// if you want to return people data if some competences.asset.id not in select
const xSort = people.filter((item) => item.competences.filter((x) => select.indexOf(x.asset.id) === -1).length > 0);

console.log(sort);
console.log(xSort);
```

Comment: @ArshpreetWadhra  If asset id object in people array (asset id = '234')  is  in array `select`('234')  return empty array

Comment: @Umbro const sort = people.filter((item) => item.competences.filter((x) => select.indexOf(x.asset.id) === -1).length === item.competences.length);
   this will check all asset id inside competences, if no id should inside select then it will return people object else not

Comment: Please share expected output json result you want.

Comment: `obj["competences"].map(competences => competences['asset']['id']) = '234'; `select[0] = '234'`. Expected output: `obj = [ ]`

Comment: obj["competences"].map(competences => competences['asset']['id']) it will give you array of all ids ['234'] and select[0] is first element if we take given array then its 123. if you want to compare then you have to run filter through your generated id array and compare if exist inside select array